# How to get Minecraft to work in my Oculus Rift?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, oculus-rift

I've recently got my Oculus Rift and one thing that got me excited during the period the Rift was developed was the prospect of playing Minecraft in VR. So I searched the internet on how to get the game running in VR which, so far, has been a bit disappointing.

As far as I can tell, the [Minecrift mod](https://minecraft-vr.com/) is no longer actively developed and the version that can be downloaded from either the mod-maker's website seems to be compatible with Rift DK2, but the consumer version is not mentioned. Of course, Microsoft also announced VR support on the PE/ Windows 10 version, but so far I can only find it for the Gear, not the Rift.

So my question is, can I, and if so how, get the consumer version of the Oculus Rift working on my pc with any version of Minecraft? Any (preferably first-hand) information on official Rift support on the Windows 10 version of Minecraft is also appreciated.

Comment: For what it is worth. This is your current support for minecraft VR: https://minecraft.net/en/vr/
I know that minecraft supported the Rift sometime in the past, I have used it for school. I'm trying to find it again. But this was certainly not for windows 10.

Comment: As this does not provide a full answer, here are still some links: http://riftinfo.com/best-oculus-rift-minecraft-setup-guide-up-to-date http://www.roadtovr.com/guide-how-to-install-minecraft-oculus-rift-dk2-minecrift/
If I'm correct, I've used these with succes in the past.

Comment: @cruelcat, thanks for the link. At least I have a place to check now. As for the set-up page. I had already found that, but it uses the MineCrift mod, which has only DK2 support as far as i can tell.

Comment: Have you already tried to use the mod? Who knows that it somehow is compatible? Worth a shot Right?

Answer (score 2):

MineCrift has evolved into ViveCraft, targeting the HTC Vive and OpenVR (see: http://www.vivecraft.org/ ). It has support for a seated experience so it can be used with the Oculus Rift as well.
In the mean time Microsoft has released the Minecraft update for Windows 10 on the Oculus Store, so there is something to choose now.

Both mod and Windows 10 solution have options to customize the way you interact with and view the world, although I found the mod a bit easier to customize since I prefer a keyboard and mouse over a controller.
You sadly can't rebind keys in the Windows 10 version, so it has some drawbacks.
Note that the mod uses the Java version of Minecraft (v1.7.10 and v1.10.2) so you can still run other mods and use shaders (although I had issues using them).